# Como clonar formulário no lugar certo da pagina - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gente, eu usei um codigo para clonar um formulário quando o usuário clicasse no botão adicionar, mas quando ele clica em adicionar, o formulário clona embaixo do submit. Não tenho ideia de qual o problema. Me ajudem a descobrir, pf.

```js
var newid = 1;
function addForm() {
 var form = document.getElementById("form")
 var clone = form.cloneNode(true);
 clone.id = clone.id+newid;
 document.getElementById("div").appendChild(clone);
 newid = newid+1;
}

function removeForm(){
 document.getElementById("div").lastChild.remove();

}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
.container {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px rgba( 0,0,0,0.33 );
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: table;
    position: static;

}

#submit {
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #AA002B 0%,
        #DD0033);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#AA002B),
        to(#DD0033));
}

input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

select {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

.botaoimg{
    margin: 2% auto;
   
}
#mais{

   background-color: green;

}

#menos{
 
   background-color: red;
}
.button{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 49%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plus.js"></script>
  <title>FormEvents</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Onsubmit "valida se enviou" -->
    <form method="POST" onsubmit="return false">

      <!-- Metodo importante para calendário. -->



      <input type="text"  name="conteudo" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Conteudo Remessa ex: 3274" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="pedido" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Número Pedido ex: ['2020011111']" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="totPeso" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Peso total em KG: '0.5'" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="totValor" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Valor total: '500'" /><br><br>

      <select>
        <option >Package</option>
        <option >Expresso</option>
        <option >Economico</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="conta" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Conta Corrente" onblur="desfocouDoCampo()" /><br><br>
      <select name="tpColeta" onchange="mudouOpcao(this)">
        <option >S - Levar remessa até a unidade</option>
        <option >K - Solicitar coleta da Unidade</option>
      </select><br><br>  
      <select name="TipoFrete" onchange="mudouOpcao(this)">
        <option >0 - Normal</option>
        <option >1 - SubContratação</option>
        <option >2 - Redespacho</option>.
        <option >3 - Redespacho Intermediário</option>.
      </select><br><br>
<div id="div">
  <fieldset id="form">
    <legend>Informações do Produto por Unidade</legend>
    <h4>Dados DFE</h4>
    CFOP<input type="number" name="cfop" placeholder="Ex.: 6909"/>
    DANFE CTE<input type="text" name="danfeCte" placeholder="Ex.: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
    NR DOC<input type="number" name="nrDoc" placeholder="Ex.: 00000000"/>
    SERIE<input type="number" name="serie" placeholder="Ex.: 0"/>
    TP DOCUMENTO<input type="number" name="tpDocumento" placeholder="Ex.: 2"/>
    VALOR<input type="text" name="valor" placeholder="Ex.: 20.2"/>

    &nbsp

    <h4>Dados Volume</h4>
    Altura<input type="number" name="altura" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Comprimento<input type="number" name="comprimento" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Identificador<input type="text" name="identificador" placeholder="Ex.: 1234567890"/>
    Largura<input type="number" name="largura" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Peso<input type="text" name="peso" placeholder="Ex.: 1.0"/>
    <div class="botaoimg">
      <input class="button" type="button" id="mais" onclick="addForm()" id="adicionar" value="Adicionar Produto"></button>
      <input class="button" type="button" id="menos" onclick="removeForm()" id="adicionar" value="Remover Produto"></button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div>

    <!-- FIM-->
    
  </form>

</div>

  <div class="submit">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Incluir"/>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: E devia clonar onde? Você que escreveu o código? Se sim, poderia nos explicá-lo? Consegue elaborar um [mcve]? Tem muito código aí que não é essencial para a solução do problema e poderia ser removido.

Comment: Feche a `div` antes de `<!-- FIM -->`. Ao invés de `<div>`, utilize `</div>`

Comment: Além disso tu estais usando o elemento `input` para o botão, mas está utilizando `</button>` para fechar esse elemento (Isso não faz sentido).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @Andy lima.

O "problema" no seu código esta na posição que o javascript "clona" o formulário. 
No seu exemplo a linha que "clona"* o formulário em determinada posição é essa:

```
document.getElementById("div").appendChild(clone);
```

*ver comentários sobre a função do appendChild();
Porém o que o javascript estava fazendo ai é tentando encontrar um elemento no seu documento com o id "div" por isso a função se chama getElementeById().
Mas pelo que vi no seu html não tem um bloco com esse id.

Eu deduzi que o bloco que você queria clonar era logo abaixo do comentário:

```
    <!-- FIM-->
```

Por isso o que eu fiz foi inserir um id "colar" no "" que vem logo antes.

Dessa forma o código novo ficou assim:

```
document.getElementById("colar").appendChild(clone);
```

E a div ficou:

```
 <div id="colar">
```

Dessa maneira o javascript agora vai procurar pelo id "colar" que inserimos como citado e colocar o conteúdo ali.

Fora isso, seria legal efetuar as correções citadas no comentário para que seu código fique correto e não apresente mais problemas.

Espero ter ajudado e fico a disposição.

Abraço

```js
var newid = 1;
function addForm() {
 var form = document.getElementById("form")
 var clone = form.cloneNode(true);
 clone.id = clone.id+newid;
 document.getElementById("colar").appendChild(clone);
 newid = newid+1;
}

function removeForm(){
 document.getElementById("div").lastChild.remove();

}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
.container {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px rgba( 0,0,0,0.33 );
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: table;
    position: static;

}

#submit {
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #AA002B 0%,
        #DD0033);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#AA002B),
        to(#DD0033));
}

input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

select {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

.botaoimg{
    margin: 2% auto;
   
}
#mais{

   background-color: green;

}

#menos{
 
   background-color: red;
}
.button{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 49%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plus.js"></script>
  <title>FormEvents</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Onsubmit "valida se enviou" -->
    <form method="POST" onsubmit="return false">

      <!-- Metodo importante para calendário. -->



      <input type="text"  name="conteudo" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Conteudo Remessa ex: 3274" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="pedido" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Número Pedido ex: ['2020011111']" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="totPeso" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Peso total em KG: '0.5'" /><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="totValor" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Valor total: '500'" /><br><br>

      <select>
        <option >Package</option>
        <option >Expresso</option>
        <option >Economico</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="text"  name="conta" onfocus="focouNoCampo()" placeholder="Conta Corrente" onblur="desfocouDoCampo()" /><br><br>
      <select name="tpColeta" onchange="mudouOpcao(this)">
        <option >S - Levar remessa até a unidade</option>
        <option >K - Solicitar coleta da Unidade</option>
      </select><br><br>  
      <select name="TipoFrete" onchange="mudouOpcao(this)">
        <option >0 - Normal</option>
        <option >1 - SubContratação</option>
        <option >2 - Redespacho</option>.
        <option >3 - Redespacho Intermediário</option>.
      </select><br><br>
<div id="div">
  <fieldset id="form">
    <legend>Informações do Produto por Unidade</legend>
    <h4>Dados DFE</h4>
    CFOP<input type="number" name="cfop" placeholder="Ex.: 6909"/>
    DANFE CTE<input type="text" name="danfeCte" placeholder="Ex.: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000"/>
    NR DOC<input type="number" name="nrDoc" placeholder="Ex.: 00000000"/>
    SERIE<input type="number" name="serie" placeholder="Ex.: 0"/>
    TP DOCUMENTO<input type="number" name="tpDocumento" placeholder="Ex.: 2"/>
    VALOR<input type="text" name="valor" placeholder="Ex.: 20.2"/>

    &nbsp

    <h4>Dados Volume</h4>
    Altura<input type="number" name="altura" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Comprimento<input type="number" name="comprimento" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Identificador<input type="text" name="identificador" placeholder="Ex.: 1234567890"/>
    Largura<input type="number" name="largura" placeholder="Ex.: 10"/>
    Peso<input type="text" name="peso" placeholder="Ex.: 1.0"/>
    <div class="botaoimg">
      <input class="button" type="button" id="mais" onclick="addForm()" id="adicionar" value="Adicionar Produto"></button>
      <input class="button" type="button" id="menos" onclick="removeForm()" id="adicionar" value="Remover Produto"></input>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div id="colar">

    <!-- FIM-->
  </div>  
  </form>



  <div class="submit">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Incluir"/>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duas ressalvas. 1 - O elemento com o *id#div* existe. Pode ser encontrado em`<div id="div">`. 2 - O `appendChild` não clona o elemento em determinada posição, ele apenas inclui o elemento.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr verdade, agora que vi essa div ali... Sobre o appendChild "clonar" foi a forma mais didática que encontrei de explicar, por isso coloquei "problema" entre aspas, faltou colocar um "clonar" entre aspars também. Valeu pelo feedback =)

Comment: eu descobri o problema, mas muito obrigada por ajudar !!!!!! queria votar na sua resposta, mas nao sei se é possivel aqui , entao considere que votei/ curti ela kkkk

Comment: Legal que deu certo, se possível depois poste suas correções para ficar como material de estudo pra quem precisar. Precisando estamos ai =)